# 'char_length' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: char

I'm new to sql and am having trouble with the char_length function.

I was hoping someone might be able to kindly advise.

[image]

I am trying to get number of characters in a string

Comment: You need to provide more information. We don't even know if this is MS Access, postgres, sql server, mysql, etc.

Answer (score 1):

By the specified image it looks like you are using SQL Server. In SQL Server you should use the `LEN` function.

```sql
SELECT CustomerName, LEN(CustomerName)
FROM dbo.Customers;
```